# C2678 error on remove from list of custom datatypes

Tags: c++

I'm currently hard at work on an assignment piece, which contains several custom datatypes. I've run into a problem where list is complaining that I am trying to remove a custom data type from a list of that same data type.

```
Error   3   error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'customer' (or there is no acceptable conversion)  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\list 1194    1   Assignment 1 - Video Store MIS
```

The relevant code is here:

```
void customerCollection::removeCustomer(customer person)
{
customers.remove(person);
}
```

and the custom data type does have a == operator defined:

```
bool customer::operator==(customer &other) const
{
return (l_fullName == other.getName()) && 
       (l_contactNumber == other.getNumber()) && 
       (l_password == other.getPassword()) && 
       (l_username == other.getUsername());
}
```

Is there any reason that the list type can't see the overloaded operator?

The customerCollection and customer data types are required parts of the program.

[EDIT] The overloaded operator is defined as public in the header file.

Comment: You don't need to call `get` on the `other` `Customer`. Use `l_fullName == other.l_fullName`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bool customer::operator==(customer &other) const
```

Try changing that to

```
bool customer::operator==(const customer &other) const
```

It is possible the code of the `customers` collection passes a const-qualified customer to the equality operator. At least, it is more idiomatic (and logical).

Comment: Ahh I see, I had to go through and make all the get functions const as well. I had tried this before and it didn't work. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm inclined to say the reason is that the parameter is not `const`:

```
 bool customer::operator==(const customer& other) const
```

depending on how `remove` is defined.